# Wake on LAN on Uverse Router

Tags: networking, lan, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to set up Wake on LAN on my Uverse 2WIRE router, and running in to issues. I can't figure out how to set up UDP Port 9 forwarding.

I was using [this tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan), but got stuck at the UDP Port 9 forwarding bit. I've never tweaked much on my router, but this is the screen I get to:

[image]

I tried just putting 9 and 9 for Port (or Range), but that didn't work. Looks like a pretty simple question for someone with a bit of knowledge.

EDIT: I may be wrong about the plain old 9 not working, but I think that's the issue. Let me know if you guys think it could be something else.

Comment: I tried but it does not work if I am trying to issue the WOL from outside the LAN/ie from the internet. regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 9 in the from and to boxes then submit. It should tell you "configuration successful". Then click the back button to go back to the `Applications, Pinholes and DMZ` page. Select your computer and find "Wake on LAN" in the application list and add it. Then click save and you're done.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

resmon6 is quite correct. Those are the needed steps. Note, however, that these 2wire routers tend to "forget" the routing for sleeping devices. My experience has been that I can successfully send the magic packet (Wake-on-LAN activating packet) to my sleeping devices only during the first 20 minutes or so of them going to sleep. After that, the router flushes its cache, and no amount of magic packets end up making it to the sleeping devices NIC's (network interface cards).

In theory, the ability to access the router's ARP settings would alleviate this, by instructing the router to remember the MAC addresses of devices, but I have found no way to access such commands.

Comment: This seems to be happening to my Pace 5268 as well.